# SQL - Finding newest dates in a field and data attached to those records

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the following information - Where a shipment can have hundreds of cases on it, I only want the last case that was created and the shipment details that go along with it. It seems that setting MAX(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) or MIN(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) both return the FIRST (Oldest) case to be created and not the LAST (Most recent).

This query would be expect to return all shipments in the last week and their most recently created case.

```
SELECT AH.TRLR_NBR, AH.SHPMT_NBR, AH.SHPD_DATE, AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME, 
MAX(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME), CH.CASE_NBR FROM ASN_HDR AH
INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH
ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
WHERE CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY AH.TRLR_NBR, AH.SHPMT_NBR, AH.SHPD_DATE, AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME, CH.CASE_NBR
ORDER BY AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
```

Comment: `ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME` also in the `GROUP BY` ? Probably, only one record is in the grouped data.. So `MAX` = `MIN`. Add a `count(1)` too to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ordering the aggregations:

```
SELECT AH.TRLR_NBR
     , AH.SHPMT_NBR
     , AH.SHPD_DATE
     , AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
     , MAX(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) KEEP
         (DENSE_RANK LAST
          ORDER BY CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) CREATE_DATE_TIME
     , MAX(CH.CASE_NBR) KEEP
         (DENSE_RANK LAST
          ORDER BY CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) CASE_NBR
FROM ASN_HDR AH
     INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH
       ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
WHERE AH.SHPD_DATE > SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY AH.TRLR_NBR
       , AH.SHPMT_NBR
       , AH.SHPD_DATE
       , AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
ORDER BY AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

The analytic [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm) function is a great tool for getting the entire row based on a max/min value in the row.

This query will rank the create date for each shipment. The ranking is based on `CREATE_DATE_TIME` in descending order so the most recent will come first:

```
SELECT
  AH.TRLR_NBR,
  AH.SHPMT_NBR,
  AH.SHPD_DATE,
  AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,
  CH.CASE_NBR,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY AH.SHPMT_NBR
    ORDER BY CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME DESC) AS CreateRank
FROM ASN_HDR AH
INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
WHERE CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-7
```

Now that you have them ranked, you can limit the end results to rows which have `CreateRank = 1`. Unfortunately you can't do that directly because the analytical functions run *after* any `WHERE` and `HAVING` conditions are applied. Instead, you need to push this into a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    AH.TRLR_NBR,
    AH.SHPMT_NBR,
    AH.SHPD_DATE,
    AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,
    CH.CASE_NBR,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY AH.SHPMT_NBR
      ORDER BY CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME DESC) AS CreateRank
  FROM ASN_HDR AH
  INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
  WHERE CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-7
) WHERE CreateRank = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to vet the max(CREATE_DATE_TIME) beforehand, using a CTE, and then filter your primary query results by a join to the CTE. This means more work before the query runs, but less work when the primary query executes, as long as you have proper supporting indexes. Something along the lines of:

```
;WITH YourCTE AS
(
SELECT AH.SHPMT_NBR, max(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) AS [CREATE_DATE_TIME]
FROM ASN_HDR AH
INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH
ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
WHERE CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY AH.SHPMT_NBR 
)

SELECT AH.TRLR_NBR
, AH.SHPMT_NBR
, AH.SHPD_DATE
, AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
, cte.CREATE_DATE_TIME
, CH.CASE_NBR 
FROM ASN_HDR AH
INNER JOIN CASE_HDR CH
ON CH.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR = AH.SHPMT_NBR
INNER JOIN YourCTE cte 
ON AH.SHPMT_NBR = cte.SHPMT_NBR AND CH.CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME = cte.CREATE_DATE_TIME
ORDER BY AH.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME
```